# Parse XML file nodes and store it to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LanguagePacks>
  <Language name = "EN">
    <item key="play" value="play"/>
    <item key="pause" value="pause"/>
    <item key="resume" value="resume"/>
    <item key="all" value="all"/>
    <item key="songs" value="songs"/>
    <item key="song" value="song"/>
    <item key="skip" value="skip"/>
    <item key="next" value="next"/>
    <item key="previous" value="previous"/>
    <item key="number" value="number"/>
    <item key="album" value="album"/>
  </Language>
  <Language name = "DE">
    <item key="play" value="spiel"/>
    <item key="pause" value="pause"/>
    <item key="resume" value="resume"/>
    <item key="all" value="alle"/>
    <item key="songs" value="lieder"/>
    <item key="song" value="lied"/>
    <item key="skip" value="skipp"/>
    <item key="next" value="nachste"/>
    <item key="previous" value="vorheriger"/>
    <item key="number" value="nummer"/>
    <item key="album" value="alben"/>
  </Language>
</LanguagePacks>
```

I want to parse the above xml file for Language name == "EN" and store the key value pairs in a dictionary. The code I am trying in below.. But error shows item with same key is already been added. Please help.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load($"{path}");
    var output = doc.Element("LanguagePacks")
        .Descendants().Where(r=>(string)r.Attribute("name").Value == "EN")
        .Descendants()
        .ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.Value);
```

Comment: You surely don´t want the decendants of the decendants of `LanguagePacks`. I think you can just remove the second `Descendants`-call. Otherwise you surely have two `items` named `play`, for instance.

Comment: Try following :             Dictionary<string,string> output = doc.Descendants("Language").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "EN").FirstOrDefault().Elements("item")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("key"), y => (string)y.Attribute("value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.Value);
```

k is an `item`, if you want your `Dictionary` like

```
[0] = {[play, play]}
[1] = {[pause, pause]}
```

I think for each `item`, you access the attribute to get value

```
var output = doc.Element("LanguagePacks")
        .Descendants().Where(r=>(string)r.Attribute("name").Value == "EN")
        .Descendants() // list of item
        .ToDictionary(k => k.Attribute("key").Value, v => k.Attribute("value").Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

`ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.Value)` will not work the way you want, because the `Name` and  `Value` properties are the node name (`item`) and node contents (nothing), not the xml attributes `"key"` and `"value"`.

You also should not use `Descendants` when you actually only want to loop through elements on one level.
Running your code on your example XML gives a NullReferenceException, because some descendants of `<LanguagePacks>` does not have a `name` attribute, and you assume they all do.

This code should do what you want. Note that this will also crash if you have duplicate keys, or if an `<item />` element is missing the key or value attributes.

```
doc.Element("LanguagePacks")
    .Elements("Language")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("name")?.Value == "EN")
    .Elements("item")
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("key").Value, x => x.Attribute("value").Value)
    .Dump();
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
.ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.Value);
```

`k.Name` will always be `item`, not the value of `key="..."`.

And I guess that `v.Value` will always be `""`, not entirely sure.

Comment: And what is the solution? That answer isn´t much helpful.